# Can't find the Task Name column in MS Project 2013

Tags: ms-project-2013

When I create a new project in MS Project 2013, there is no option to add the Task Name column.
I've tried clicking on *Add New Column* but Task Name doesn't appear there:
[image]

The following (from a different computer) is what I'm trying to find:

[image]

Comment: I believe the column is "Name"

Comment: Confirmed - the name of the field is "Name" - "Task Name" is merely a display name which can be configured by adjusting the column header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark C. Wallace is correct, the field name is "Name"