# What is the field name of Resource Names in MS Project

Tags: ms-project

I'm trying to identify the field name of Resource Names, which I believe is an out of the box MS Project column. I need this information to map this field into a ServiceNow import and came across this post:
[Can't find the Task Name column in MS Project 2013](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/21267/cant-find-the-task-name-column-in-ms-project-2013/21274#21274?newreg=9efdf79edde441c28536b0d48783ff6c)

Where the community identified that the "Task Name" labeled field has a field name of "Name"

What is the equivalent field name value of Resource Names? I do not have a license for MS Project and I'm not able to dig for this myself.

Another way to phrase the question: I'm in contact with a user that does have MS project access, what can I tell them to do to confirm the field name of Resource Names? We were able to achieve our mapping requirements with a custom field, when reviewing that field's Field Settings I see Field Name: Text1 (Custom Field Name) and the import mapping works if I specify Text1 as the MS Project column name in ServiceNow.

How do I see the equivalent value, of Text1 in that example, to Resource Names?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [list of all fields](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/available-fields-reference-615a4563-1cc3-40f4-b66f-1b17e793a460). Under Task fields, you'll see the name of that field is [Resource Names](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/resource-names-task-field-9000102b-2622-4f40-8619-6061ff964376).

However, looking at the ServiceNow [project field mapping](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/utah-it-business-management/page/product/project-management/reference/r_ProjectFieldMapping.html), it appears that Resource Names is not a field that gets imported. Rather:

> Note: During import, if there are multiple resources assigned to a
> task in Microsoft Project:
>
> ```
> The first resource is added to the Assigned to field.
> The rest of the resources are added to the Additional assignee list field.
> ```

If you still want Resource Names as it appears in MS Project, you could create a custom field in Project that mirrors the Resource Names field and then build a custom import map that includes that field. (e.g. customize Text1 with a formula = [Resource Names])

Comment: Thank you for the response. To be clear, the import I'm doing is the import of an .mpp file exported from MS Project and imported into ServiceNow.

All of the other task values seem to map correctly except Resource Names. It feels like there is some sort of internal MS Project field name other than this label that neds to be specified but the only way I've gotten anything to map is by creating that Custom field and mapping it from "Text1" in ServiceNow, that is showing at least some (but not all) of the values mapping correctly.